# Print more than 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, azure, union

I want to print out 2 or more tables in the SQL azure, but i'm trying to using UNION and UNION ALL but it still have the same error which is

Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Query12, Line 7
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

```sql
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE Query12
@date_job_completed varchar(50),
@Department_number int
AS

BEGIN
With q as(
    SELECT Job.Job_no, type_of_machine_use, amount_of_time_machine_use, martirial_used, labor_time, date_job_completed as Print_out
    FROM Cut_job
    INNER JOIN Job ON Job.Job_no = Cut_job.Job_no
    INNER JOIN No_of_Process ON No_of_Process.Process_id = Job.Process_id
    INNER JOIN Department ON Department.Department_number = No_of_Process.Department_number
    WHERE Cut_job.date_job_completed = @date_job_completed AND Department.Department_number = @Department_number
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT Job.Job_no, Color, Volume, labor_time, date_job_completed as Print_out
    FROM Paint_job
    INNER JOIN Job ON Job.Job_no = Paint_job.Job_no
    INNER JOIN No_of_Process ON No_of_Process.Process_id = Job.Process_id
    INNER JOIN Department ON Department.Department_number = No_of_Process.Department_number
    WHERE Paint_job.date_job_completed = @date_job_completed AND Department.Department_number = @Department_number
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT Job.Job_no, labor_time, date_job_completed as Print_out
    FROM Fit_job
    INNER JOIN Job ON Job.Job_no = Fit_job.Job_no
    INNER JOIN No_of_Process ON No_of_Process.Process_id = Job.Process_id
    INNER JOIN Department ON Department.Department_number = No_of_Process.Department_number
    WHERE Fit_job.date_job_completed = @date_job_completed AND Department.Department_number = @Department_number
) 
SELECT Print_out
FROM q
END
GO
EXEC Query12 @date_job_completed = '23/23/2019', @Department_number = 4;
```

Comment: And what exactly about the error message don't you understand? To further clarify also provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Do so by [edit]ing the question. Don't use comments for such important information.

Comment: Add NULL's to the shorter column list until you get the same number.

Comment: or, you know, include the same columns in each query...

Comment: Sorry i should asked clearly. Everything is print out fine in SQL but when i connect it into Java to print out all 3 tables, The java print out 3 tables but it just read only 1 value of the first table

Comment: Please update your question rather than answering on comments.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule for combining the result set of two or more queries by using UNION, UINON ALL, EXCEPT or INTERSECT are:

- The number and order of the columns in the query must be same
- And the data types should be compatible.

If this is not followed you will encounter the error as below.

[image]

If you do not have the same column list in all queries to avoid the errors, you can add NULL columns to the missing column list as below.

[image]